# Can i add custom field on Add account team page

Tags: visualforce, account, account-teams

Is it possible to add a custom field on Account Team?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Customization of Add to Account Team, can be done by adding the custom field on the Account Team Member and adding the same field on multiline editor for Account team layout.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sales_feature_core_accounts.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you simply wanted to add custom fields to *Account Teams*, then you can go to the object settings for `Account Team Member` and add the custom fields.

If you wanted to display additional custom fields in the ***Add Team Members*** page, you can do so by creating a custom ***VF Page*** (*with custom fields*) and then override the ***Add Team Member(s)*** button to display the custom VF Page. The SF object you are want to configure is `Account Team Member`. From object settings page, go to `Account Team Member` > `Buttons and Links` (see screenshot below for ref).

[image]

Edit `Add Team Member` or `Add Team Members` button and override with the custom VF page (see screenshot below for ref).

[image]

In Salesforce classic, you can directly go to the `Buttons & Links` set-up page using the following URL (***replace <My Domain> with your org domain name***):

```
https://<My Domain>.my.salesforce.com/p/setup/link/ActionButtonLinkList?pageName=AccountTeamMember&type=AccountTeamMember&setupid=AccountTeamMemberLinks&retURL=%2Fui%2Fsetup%2FSetup%3Fsetupid%3DAccountTeamMember
```

Comment: Hi Arut, thanks but i found out with Winter'20 i can customize the layout too but this limited to Lightning users, but thanks for the reply.https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sales_feature_core_accounts.htm

Comment: This release notes mentions about general improvements made w.r.t to Account Teams, but doesn't mention anything about improvements made over ways to customize the related standard pages. Even with lightning experience, you can customize the default page layout but nothing out of the box for tweaking the standard page.

Comment: Do you have any idea how the same can be done in classic, cause this helped me in lightning only.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if that works for you. Although, I've not tested this in SF classic, overriding the standard page in lightning should reflect in classic too.